# Using Git as a Git server between two Macs?

Tags: macos, git

If there are two Macs, is there a simple way that a Mac can be set up as a Git server, so that both Xcode and push and pull from this server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the two Macs have a network connection between them (doesn't have to be direct, just that they can access each other) you could use git+ssh on one (or both) to get to the repo on the other (or the "server" repo).

From the Git book: [4.4 Git on the Server - Setting Up the Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server).

OSX should already have a running SSHd. For security, it might be wise to create a user on the "server" which the users of the two Macs can access.